# extracting something from a dataframe which contain lists with label information

Tags: r

Sorry if this is basic, I have great difficulty knowing how to extract things out of dataframes, especially when there are lists and other items contained within.
Please see below image of what I see when I click on the dataframe in the global environment. I have a dataframe (lets call it "df") with the variable S1 (it was SPSS file imported using Haven).

[![how it looks in environment][1]][1]
[image]

I know df$S1 gets me the values for the variable. But I'd just like to extract the information that is value "labels" and "names" and put them into another dataframe.  Is there a way to do it? I'd like to do it for all variables, but if you can start me off just to extract these two from that one variable, I can look at doing it using a loop. Any help greatly appreciated. Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `attr` or `attributes`

```
attributes(df$S1)
```

returns a `list` with the key as the names `label`, `format.spss` etc.  From the above, just use the `$` or `[[` for extraction i.e. for the normal `list`

```
attributes(df$S1)$label
```

Based on the updated image, we may need `@`

```
attributes(df$S1)@label
```

---

If we use `attr`

```
attr(df$S1, "label")
```

Comment: sorry, I just updated the picture, it has @ signs, sorry

Comment: @H.Cheung CAn you check the output of `attributes(df$S1)`. Perhaps you need `attributes(df$S1)@label`

Comment: yes, fantastic! Sorry I have issues with data that isn't a flat dataset, to me they all look very different. Thank you for showing me "attr" and explaining. Cheers